# INSERT failure with SQLAlchemy ORM / SQL Server 2017 - Invalid Object Name

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, sql-server-2017, python-3.9

Firstly, I have seen many answers which is specific to the Invalid Object Name error working with SQL Server, but None of them seem to solve my problem. I don't have much idea on SQL Server dialect, but here is my current setup required on the project.

- SQL Server 2017
- SQLAlchemy (pyodbc+mssql)
- Python 3.9

I'm trying to insert a database row, using the SQLAlchemy ORM, but it fails to resolve the schema and table, giving me the error of type

> (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'agent.dbo.tasks'.
> (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

I'm creating a `session` with the following code.

```
engine = create_engine(connection_string, pool_size=10, max_overflow=5,
                       pool_use_lifo=False, pool_pre_ping=True, echo=True, echo_pool=True)
db_session_manager = sessionmaker()
db_session_manager.configure(bind=engine)
session = db_session_manager()
```

I have a task object defined like

```
class Task(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "tasks"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "agent.dbo"}
    # .. field defs
```

I'm trying to fill the object fields and then do the insert like the usual

```
task = Task()
task.tid = 1
...
session.add(task)
session.commit()
```

But this fails, with the error mentioned before. I tried to execute a direct query like

```
session.execute("SELECT * FROM agent.dbo.tasks")
```

And it returned a result set.
The connection string is a `URL` object, which prints like

```
mssql+pyodbc://task-user:******@CRD4E0050L/agent?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server
```

I tried to use the SQL Server Management Studio to insert manually and check, there it shown me a sql dialect with `[]` as field separators
like

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tasks]
           ([tid]..
```

, but SQLAlchemy on echo did not show that, instead it used the one I see in MySQL like

```
INSERT INTO agent.dbo.tasks (onbase_handle_id,..
```

What is that I'm doing wrong ? I thought SQLAlchemy if configured with a supported dialect, should work fine (I use it on MySQL quite well). Am I missing any configuration ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try simply omitting `__table_args__` and see if that works.

Comment: You're connected to the wrong database. Change your connection string, or add a `USE` statement. Ideally you shouldn't need to specify the database name (is that `agent`?)

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks! It did work after commenting that line. Can you tell me why so? Usually I give the schema name with MySQL for it to work for cross db joins and all.

Comment: It was just a guess on my part. You connection URL showed that `agent` was the database and `dbo` is a very common default schema so there was a good chance that the `__table_args__` was redundant. It's not *wrong*, at least as it is shown in your question, so double-check it in your code. (Maybe there is a typo.)

Comment: Sure. I will update back my findings later. Thanks for the guess! :-)